# Virtualbox and laptop webcamera

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, webcam

I am using Win7 64bit Ultimate on HP's EliteBook 8560p and I am running Ubuntu 10.04 32bit in virtualbox. How do I access integrated notebook's webcamera from virtualized Ubuntu? I have installed neccessary  support for USB (I am not sure if I need this USB support for integrated webcame).

Answer (score 0):

Normally most of the cameras are listed as USB devices.
If you have a running VirtualBox, go to menu 
Devices -> USB-devices and select the one you want to attach to virtual machine

Comment: VirtualBox freezes everytime when I try to access my webcamera trough USB devices.